# A question about dimension of SL(2,C) character variety of knot group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, character-varieties

It is known that if there isn't a closed essential surface in $S^3 \setminus K$, the dimension of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ character variety is $1$. (In fact, it holds for a general 3-manifold, not only for a knot complement. )

Is there any known counter-example of a knot for the converse, i.e., a knot $K$ where a closed essential surface exists in $S^3\setminus K$ and $\dim_{\mathbb C}( \chi_{SL(2,\mathbb C)}(S^3\setminus K))=1$?

Answer (score 3):

In [*Incompressible surfaces in tunnel number one knot complements*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864199000401) by Mario Eudave-Muñoz, Figure 7 gives an example of a knot with a closed essential surface.  The author guesses it is the least volume example.  The volume computed is 6.2597017011.

Using [SnapPy](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/), one sees that knot 343 on the census also has this volume, and so the knot in Figure 7 appears to be K8_143 (I thank Mario Eudave-Muñoz for pointing this out to me).

From SnapPy this knot has fundamental group $$\langle a,b\ | \ aaaabAAAABaaaBAAAAbaaaabbbb\rangle$$ where $A=a^{-1}$ and $B=b^{-1}.$

In my paper, with JP Burelle and Caleb Ashley, *[Rank 1 character varieties of finitely presented groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08241)* an effective algorithm is described to compute the $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$-character variety of any finitely presented group $\Gamma$.  This algorithm has been integrated into [SnapPy](https://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/additional_classes.html#snappy.HolonomyGroup.character_variety_vars_and_polys).

Using SnapPy, I computed relations that cut-out the $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$-character variety of K8_143.  Here is the code:

```
M=CensusKnots[343]
G=M.fundamental_group()
G.character_variety_vars_and_polys()
```

I then used [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/) to compute the dimension.  Here is the code (the second input comes from the output from SnapPy):

```
R=QQ[Ta,Tb,Tab]
I=ideal((-Tb^2 + 1)*Ta^20 + (3*Tab*Tb^3 - 4*Tab*Tb)*Ta^19 + ((-3*Tab^2 - 3)*Tb^4 + (3*Tab^2 + 24)*Tb^2 + (2*Tab^2 - 20))*Ta^18 + ((Tab^3 + 6*Tab)*Tb^5 + (2*Tab^3 - 60*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-6*Tab^3 + 68*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^17 + ((-3*Tab^2 - 3)*Tb^6 + (-2*Tab^4 + 42*Tab^2 + 54)*Tb^4 + (3*Tab^4 - 30*Tab^2 - 236)*Tb^2 + (Tab^4 - 32*Tab^2 + 170))*Ta^16 + (3*Tab*Tb^7 + (-6*Tab^3 - 84*Tab)*Tb^5 + (Tab^5 - 40*Tab^3 + 480*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-2*Tab^5 + 80*Tab^3 - 484*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^15 + (-Tb^8 + (27*Tab^2 + 40)*Tb^6 + (19*Tab^4 - 222*Tab^2 - 396)*Tb^4 + (-26*Tab^4 + 90*Tab^2 + 1252)*Tb^2 + (-12*Tab^4 + 212*Tab^2 - 800))*Ta^14 + (-28*Tab*Tb^7 + (2*Tab^3 + 468*Tab)*Tb^5 + (-10*Tab^5 + 272*Tab^3 - 2020*Tab)*Tb^3 + (20*Tab^5 - 436*Tab^3 + 1872*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^13 + (9*Tb^8 + (-94*Tab^2 - 212)*Tb^6 + (-71*Tab^4 + 560*Tab^2 + 1538)*Tb^4 + (84*Tab^4 + 37*Tab^2 - 3939)*Tb^2 + (58*Tab^4 - 753*Tab^2 + 2275))*Ta^12 + (104*Tab*Tb^7 + (64*Tab^3 - 1344*Tab)*Tb^5 + (40*Tab^5 - 898*Tab^3 + 4886*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-80*Tab^5 + 1251*Tab^3 - 4266*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^11 + (-32*Tb^8 + (152*Tab^2 + 576)*Tb^6 + (129*Tab^4 - 641*Tab^2 - 3430)*Tb^4 + (-113*Tab^4 - 778*Tab^2 + 7565)*Tb^2 + (-145*Tab^4 + 1550*Tab^2 - 4004))*Ta^10 + (-192*Tab*Tb^7 + (-194*Tab^3 + 2118*Tab)*Tb^5 + (-81*Tab^5 + 1592*Tab^3 - 6884*Tab)*Tb^3 + (162*Tab^5 - 2018*Tab^3 + 5792*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^9 + (56*Tb^8 + (-95*Tab^2 - 851)*Tb^6 + (-109*Tab^4 + 94*Tab^2 + 4425)*Tb^4 + (19*Tab^4 + 1784*Tab^2 - 8752)*Tb^2 + (199*Tab^4 - 1861*Tab^2 + 4290))*Ta^8 + (176*Tab*Tb^7 + (235*Tab^3 - 1762*Tab)*Tb^5 + (86*Tab^5 - 1502*Tab^3 + 5376*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-172*Tab^5 + 1797*Tab^3 - 4494*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^7 + (-48*Tb^8 + (-21*Tab^2 + 655)*Tb^6 + (23*Tab^4 + 446*Tab^2 - 3124)*Tb^4 + (99*Tab^4 - 1793*Tab^2 + 5754)*Tb^2 + (-145*Tab^4 + 1238*Tab^2 - 2640))*Ta^6 + (-64*Tab*Tb^7 + (-116*Tab^3 + 640*Tab)*Tb^5 + (-44*Tab^5 + 664*Tab^3 - 2001*Tab)*Tb^3 + (88*Tab^5 - 796*Tab^3 + 1786*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^5 + (16*Tb^8 + (40*Tab^2 - 216)*Tb^6 + (16*Tab^4 - 319*Tab^2 + 1028)*Tb^4 + (-80*Tab^4 + 786*Tab^2 - 1881)*Tb^2 + (48*Tab^4 - 396*Tab^2 + 825))*Ta^4 + ((12*Tab^3 - 41*Tab)*Tb^5 + (8*Tab^5 - 89*Tab^3 + 233*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-16*Tab^5 + 134*Tab^3 - 294*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^3 + ((-4*Tab^2 + 12)*Tb^6 + (-4*Tab^4 + 38*Tab^2 - 97)*Tb^4 + (12*Tab^4 - 96*Tab^2 + 222)*Tb^2 + (-4*Tab^4 + 40*Tab^2 - 100))*Ta^2 + (2*Tab*Tb^5 + (2*Tab^3 - 14*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-4*Tab^3 + 20*Tab)*Tb - 1)*Ta + (Tb^4 - 4*Tb^2 + 2),
  (-Tb^3 + 2*Tb)*Ta^19 + (3*Tab*Tb^4 - 7*Tab*Tb^2 + Tab)*Ta^18 + ((-3*Tab^2 - 3)*Tb^5 + (6*Tab^2 + 26)*Tb^3 + (2*Tab^2 - 39)*Tb)*Ta^17 + ((Tab^3 + 6*Tab)*Tb^6 + (Tab^3 - 63*Tab)*Tb^4 + (-9*Tab^3 + 115*Tab)*Tb^2 + (2*Tab^3 - 17*Tab))*Ta^16 + ((-3*Tab^2 - 3)*Tb^7 + (-2*Tab^4 + 42*Tab^2 + 54)*Tb^5 + (5*Tab^4 - 63*Tab^2 - 262)*Tb^3 + (-36*Tab^2 + 320)*Tb)*Ta^15 + (3*Tab*Tb^8 + (-5*Tab^3 - 81*Tab)*Tb^6 + (Tab^5 - 33*Tab^3 + 501*Tab)*Tb^4 + (-3*Tab^5 + 117*Tab^3 - 778*Tab)*Tb^2 + (Tab^5 - 26*Tab^3 + 120*Tab))*Ta^14 + (-Tb^9 + (24*Tab^2 + 38)*Tb^7 + (17*Tab^4 - 210*Tab^2 - 384)*Tb^5 + (-40*Tab^4 + 228*Tab^2 + 1372)*Tb^3 + (-5*Tab^4 + 256*Tab^2 - 1435)*Tb)*Ta^13 + (-25*Tab*Tb^8 + (-2*Tab^3 + 421*Tab)*Tb^6 + (-9*Tab^5 + 238*Tab^3 - 2016*Tab)*Tb^4 + (27*Tab^5 - 602*Tab^3 + 2803*Tab)*Tb^2 + (-9*Tab^5 + 136*Tab^3 - 455*Tab))*Ta^12 + (8*Tb^9 + (-73*Tab^2 - 186)*Tb^7 + (-56*Tab^4 + 480*Tab^2 + 1406)*Tb^5 + (120*Tab^4 - 252*Tab^2 - 4129)*Tb^3 + (40*Tab^4 - 938*Tab^2 + 3824)*Tb)*Ta^11 + (82*Tab*Tb^8 + (59*Tab^3 - 1098*Tab)*Tb^6 + (32*Tab^5 - 755*Tab^3 + 4505*Tab)*Tb^4 + (-96*Tab^5 + 1582*Tab^3 - 5795*Tab)*Tb^2 + (32*Tab^5 - 367*Tab^3 + 999*Tab))*Ta^10 + (-25*Tb^9 + (98*Tab^2 + 456)*Tb^7 + (86*Tab^4 - 453*Tab^2 - 2877)*Tb^5 + (-152*Tab^4 - 420*Tab^2 + 7356)*Tb^3 + (-126*Tab^4 + 1925*Tab^2 - 6169)*Tb)*Ta^9 + (-131*Tab*Tb^8 + (-145*Tab^3 + 1521*Tab)*Tb^6 + (-56*Tab^5 + 1215*Tab^3 - 5625*Tab)*Tb^4 + (168*Tab^5 - 2244*Tab^3 + 6852*Tab)*Tb^2 + (-56*Tab^5 + 539*Tab^3 - 1269*Tab))*Ta^8 + (38*Tb^9 + (-37*Tab^2 - 595)*Tb^7 + (-52*Tab^4 - 66*Tab^2 + 3312)*Tb^5 + (32*Tab^4 + 1428*Tab^2 - 7633)*Tb^3 + (196*Tab^4 - 2232*Tab^2 + 5880)*Tb)*Ta^7 + (99*Tab*Tb^8 + (143*Tab^3 - 1045*Tab)*Tb^6 + (48*Tab^5 - 965*Tab^3 + 3612*Tab)*Tb^4 + (-144*Tab^5 + 1624*Tab^3 - 4269*Tab)*Tb^2 + (48*Tab^5 - 409*Tab^3 + 868*Tab))*Ta^6 + (-28*Tb^9 + (-36*Tab^2 + 396)*Tb^7 + (-8*Tab^4 + 420*Tab^2 - 2022)*Tb^5 + (96*Tab^4 - 1440*Tab^2 + 4316)*Tb^3 + (-152*Tab^4 + 1380*Tab^2 - 3082)*Tb)*Ta^5 + (-24*Tab*Tb^8 + (-48*Tab^3 + 250*Tab)*Tb^6 + (-16*Tab^5 + 288*Tab^3 - 876*Tab)*Tb^4 + (48*Tab^5 - 464*Tab^3 + 1082*Tab)*Tb^2 + (-16*Tab^5 + 128*Tab^3 - 260*Tab))*Ta^4 + (8*Tb^9 + (28*Tab^2 - 110)*Tb^7 + (16*Tab^4 - 218*Tab^2 + 548)*Tb^5 + (-64*Tab^4 + 536*Tab^2 - 1131)*Tb^3 + (48*Tab^4 - 374*Tab^2 + 758)*Tb)*Ta^3 + (-4*Tab*Tb^8 + (-4*Tab^3 + 24*Tab)*Tb^6 + (12*Tab^3 - 31*Tab)*Tb^4 - 19*Tab*Tb^2 + (-4*Tab^3 + 17*Tab))*Ta^2 + (4*Tb^7 + (4*Tab^2 - 33)*Tb^5 + (-16*Tab^2 + 82)*Tb^3 + (12*Tab^2 - 55)*Tb)*Ta + (-Tab*Tb^4 + 3*Tab*Tb^2 - Tb - Tab),
  (-Tb^2 + 1)*Ta^19 + (3*Tab*Tb^3 - 4*Tab*Tb)*Ta^18 + ((-3*Tab^2 - 3)*Tb^4 + (3*Tab^2 + 23)*Tb^2 + (2*Tab^2 - 19))*Ta^17 + ((Tab^3 + 6*Tab)*Tb^5 + (2*Tab^3 - 57*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-6*Tab^3 + 64*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^16 + ((-3*Tab^2 - 3)*Tb^6 + (-2*Tab^4 + 39*Tab^2 + 51)*Tb^4 + (3*Tab^4 - 27*Tab^2 - 214)*Tb^2 + (Tab^4 - 30*Tab^2 + 152))*Ta^15 + (3*Tab*Tb^7 + (-5*Tab^3 - 78*Tab)*Tb^5 + (Tab^5 - 38*Tab^3 + 426*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-2*Tab^5 + 74*Tab^3 - 424*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^14 + (-Tb^8 + (24*Tab^2 + 37)*Tb^6 + (17*Tab^4 - 186*Tab^2 - 348)*Tb^4 + (-23*Tab^4 + 66*Tab^2 + 1059)*Tb^2 + (-11*Tab^4 + 184*Tab^2 - 665))*Ta^13 + (-25*Tab*Tb^7 + (-2*Tab^3 + 396*Tab)*Tb^5 + (-9*Tab^5 + 236*Tab^3 - 1645*Tab)*Tb^3 + (18*Tab^5 - 368*Tab^3 + 1504*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^12 + (8*Tb^8 + (-73*Tab^2 - 178)*Tb^6 + (-56*Tab^4 + 407*Tab^2 + 1236)*Tb^4 + (64*Tab^4 + 82*Tab^2 - 3055)*Tb^2 + (48*Tab^4 - 595*Tab^2 + 1729))*Ta^11 + (82*Tab*Tb^7 + (59*Tab^3 - 1016*Tab)*Tb^5 + (32*Tab^5 - 696*Tab^3 + 3571*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-64*Tab^5 + 945*Tab^3 - 3076*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^10 + (-25*Tb^8 + (98*Tab^2 + 431)*Tb^6 + (86*Tab^4 - 355*Tab^2 - 2471)*Tb^4 + (-66*Tab^4 - 677*Tab^2 + 5266)*Tb^2 + (-106*Tab^4 + 1089*Tab^2 - 2717))*Ta^9 + (-131*Tab*Tb^7 + (-145*Tab^3 + 1390*Tab)*Tb^5 + (-56*Tab^5 + 1070*Tab^3 - 4366*Tab)*Tb^3 + (112*Tab^5 - 1319*Tab^3 + 3614*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^8 + (38*Tb^8 + (-37*Tab^2 - 557)*Tb^6 + (-52*Tab^4 - 103*Tab^2 + 2793)*Tb^4 + (-20*Tab^4 + 1288*Tab^2 - 5321)*Tb^2 + (124*Tab^4 - 1121*Tab^2 + 2508))*Ta^7 + (99*Tab*Tb^7 + (143*Tab^3 - 946*Tab)*Tb^5 + (48*Tab^5 - 822*Tab^3 + 2765*Tab)*Tb^3 + (-96*Tab^5 + 945*Tab^3 - 2252*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^6 + (-28*Tb^8 + (-36*Tab^2 + 368)*Tb^6 + (-8*Tab^4 + 384*Tab^2 - 1682)*Tb^4 + (88*Tab^4 - 1092*Tab^2 + 2946)*Tb^2 + (-72*Tab^4 + 600*Tab^2 - 1254))*Ta^5 + (-24*Tab*Tb^7 + (-48*Tab^3 + 226*Tab)*Tb^5 + (-16*Tab^5 + 240*Tab^3 - 674*Tab)*Tb^3 + (32*Tab^5 - 272*Tab^3 + 586*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^4 + (8*Tb^8 + (28*Tab^2 - 102)*Tb^6 + (16*Tab^4 - 190*Tab^2 + 454)*Tb^4 + (-48*Tab^4 + 374*Tab^2 - 763)*Tb^2 + (16*Tab^4 - 134*Tab^2 + 285))*Ta^3 + (-4*Tab*Tb^7 + (-4*Tab^3 + 20*Tab)*Tb^5 + (8*Tab^3 - 15*Tab)*Tb^3 + (4*Tab^3 - 22*Tab)*Tb)*Ta^2 + (4*Tb^6 + (4*Tab^2 - 29)*Tb^4 + (-12*Tab^2 + 57)*Tb^2 + (4*Tab^2 - 19))*Ta + (-Tab*Tb^3 + 2*Tab*Tb - 2))

dim I
```

The resulting output is 1.